# onSaveInstanceState() vs. onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance()

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, parcelable, android-optionsmenu, android-configchanges

I am using ActionBarSherlock, along with several `MenuItem`s that I dynamically manage, depending on program state.  Specifically, I save the `MenuItem`s into instance variables in the `Activity`'s `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method, and then can show and/or hide them as needed later in the `Activity`.

However, I found that the `MenuItem` variables can be lost on configuration changes, such as device rotation.  So I also put them into a `Parcel` and pass them to `onSaveInstanceState()` for restoral through the `savedInstanceState` mechanism in the next `onCreate()` call, if needed.

This seems to work fine in the case of a device rotation.  However, if I press the Home button, I get an error:

```
Unable to marshal value com.actionbarsherlock.internal.view.menu.MenuItemWrapper
```

Any idea what's the difference, or suggestions how to fix?  Thank you!

**UPDATE**

I found a simple solution using [`onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance%28%29).  By overriding this method you can stash an object of a class of your choice when an `Activity` is being destroyed, and then retrieve it using `getLastCustomNonConfigurationInstance()`.  This seems a lot simpler than messing with `Parcelable`s, etc., and it works in my case.

**But I'd still like to know:** why do I get the above error using `onSaveInstanceState()`?  And is it generally safe to use `onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance()`, or are there any gotchas?

Comment: The object generating the error likely does not implement Parcelable.